# can't acces key from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, key, nsdictionary

I have the following code:

```
- (id)initWithDictionaryRepresentation:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        dictionaryRepresentation = [dictionary retain];
        NSArray *allKeys = [dictionaryRepresentation allKeys];
        NSDictionary *k = [dictionaryRepresentation objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:[allKeys count] - 1]];
        NSArray *stepDics = [k objectForKey:@"Steps"];
        numerOfSteps = [stepDics count];
        steps = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numerOfSteps];
        for (NSDictionary *stepDic in stepDics) {
            [(NSMutableArray *)steps addObject:[UICGStep stepWithDictionaryRepresentation:stepDic]];
        }
          ............
}
```

My app crashes at this line:

```
 NSArray *stepDics = [k objectForKey:@"Steps"];
```

but also crashes if I try this : `NSArray *stepDics = [k objectForKey:@"pr"];`.It seems that I can't acces any of the keys!

This is how my dictionary looks like:
   http://pastebin.com/w5HSLvvT

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray *allKeys = [dictionaryRepresentation allKeys];`

Will return you the keys in an unpredictable order, so you shouldn't be using

```
id key = [allKeys objectAtIndex:[allKeys count] - 1]
```

as it could return something different every time, this is shown in the documentation for for this function in the [NSDictionary Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html).

> The order of the elements in the array is not defined

Why dont you try

```
NSDictionary* a = [dictionary objectForKey:@"A"];
NSArray* stepDics = [a objectForKey:@"Steps"];
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary will return `nil` if you ask for a key that doesn't exist. The fact that it's crashing means that you have a memory management error, not in the code you show above but in the code that creates the dictionary that is passed into your `initWithDictionaryRepresentation:` method. You're over-releasing the array that's stored in the `@"Steps"` key of the dictionary.